# Was the Greek worship of heroes similar to their worship of the gods?

Tags: greek, mythohistory, hero-cult

I just want to know the similarites and differences between god and hero worship in ancient Greece. Was there actually a difference, or were past heroes treated like gods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_hero_cult

Comment: not really, but thanks for trying.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're looking for.